# Entity Framework - How to fix the "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint" error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have class where `Team Home` and `Team Guest` another class which exist.

```
public class Match
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Tour Tour { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateMatch { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Team Home { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Team Guest { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Result Result { get; set; }
}
```

when i try add `Match`:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Teams'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Teams'. The duplicate key value is
>   (06f67648-f904-4a4e-8ceb-33c204d8267c). The statement has been
>   terminated.

i don't know how add match where `Teams` already exist

Comment: since all navigation properties are added as well, you probably had the same team in some of your navigation properties. If you only want to add the match, set those navigation properties null (leave FK as it is), so those won't be added again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DevilSuichiro correctly mentioned, you don't need to fill your navigation properties. Add foreign keys for all of your navigation properties like this:

```
public virtual int HomeId { get; set; }

[DataMember]
[ForeignKey("HomeId")]
public virtual Team Home { get; set; }
```

And then when you need to add a new `Match` just fill the `HomeId` and set `Home` property to `null` so it won't be readded to the database.